# Insert value in xml file when field match

Tags: php, xml, import, merge, load

i need to take field MASSIMALE from massimali.xml and put it on all massimale fiels on esercizi.xml where field UTENTE and ESERCIZIO match :
eg
I have one MASSIMALE to insert in many row of the same exercise.
in your solution the value of the MASSIMALE is loaded only in the first exercise and not in all the exercises with the same name and the same user

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sessioni>
  <sessione position="1">
    <id>1739616101355231</id>
    <index>1</index>
    <nome_sessione>3</nome_sessione>
    <utente>USER1</utente>    **<- MATCH WITH USER1 IN massimali.xml**
    <esercizio>BENCH PRESS</esercizio> **<- MATCH WITH USER1 IN massimali.xml**
    <rep_sessione>1</rep_sessione>
    <percent_sessione>50</percent_sessione>
    <massimale>100</massimale> <- LOAD FROM massimali.xml
```

Thank You

esercizi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sessioni>
  <sessione position="1">
    <id>1739616101355231</id>
    <index>1</index>
    <nome_sessione>3</nome_sessione>
    <utente>USER1</utente>
    <esercizio>BENCH PRESS</esercizio>
    <rep_sessione>1</rep_sessione>
    <percent_sessione>50</percent_sessione>
    <massimale/>
  </sessione>
  <sessione position="2">
    <id>1739616101355231</id>
    <index>2</index>
    <nome_sessione>3</nome_sessione>
    <utente>USER1</utente>
    <esercizio>BENCH PRESS</esercizio>
    <rep_sessione>1</rep_sessione>
    <percent_sessione>65</percent_sessione>
    <massimale/>
  </sessione>
  <sessione position="3">
    <id>1739616101355231</id>
    <index>3</index>
    <nome_sessione>3</nome_sessione>
    <utente>USER1</utente>
    <esercizio>BENCH PRESS</esercizio>
    <rep_sessione>1</rep_sessione>
    <percent_sessione>75</percent_sessione>
    <massimale/>
  </sessione>
  <sessione position="4">
    <id>1739616101355231</id>
    <index>4</index>
    <nome_sessione>3</nome_sessione>
    <utente>USER1</utente>
    <esercizio>BENCH PRESS</esercizio>
    <rep_sessione>1</rep_sessione>
    <percent_sessione>80</percent_sessione>
    <massimale/>
  </sessione>
  <sessione position="5">
    <id>1739720496368387</id>
    <index>5</index>
    <nome_sessione>1</nome_sessione>
    <utente>USER2</utente>
    <esercizio>BACK SQUAT</esercizio>
    <rep_sessione>1</rep_sessione>
    <percent_sessione>65</percent_sessione>
    <massimale/>
  </sessione>
  <sessione position="6">
    <id>1739720496368387</id>
    <index>6</index>
    <nome_sessione>1</nome_sessione>
    <utente>USER2</utente>
    <esercizio>BACK SQUAT</esercizio>
    <rep_sessione>1</rep_sessione>
    <percent_sessione>75</percent_sessione>
    <massimale/>
  </sessione>
  <sessione position="7">
    <id>1739720496368387</id>
    <index>7</index>
    <nome_sessione>1</nome_sessione>
    <utente>USER2</utente>
    <esercizio>BACK SQUAT</esercizio>
    <rep_sessione>1</rep_sessione>
    <percent_sessione>85</percent_sessione>
    <massimale/>
  </sessione>
</sessioni>
```

massimali.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<massimali>
  <atleta position="1">
    <id>1739616101355231</id>
    <utente>USER1</utente>
    <esercizio>BENCH PRESS</esercizio>
    <massimale>100</massimale>
    <data>2022-07-30</data>
  </atleta>
  <atleta position="2">
    <id>1739720496368387</id>
    <utente>USER1</utente>
    <esercizio>BACK SQUAT</esercizio>
    <massimale>80</massimale>
    <data>2022-07-30</data>
  </atleta>
  <atleta position="3">
    <id>1739720496368387</id>
    <utente>USER2</utente>
    <esercizio>BACK SQUAT</esercizio>
    <massimale>100</massimale>
    <data>2022-07-30</data>
  </atleta>
  <atleta position="4">
    <id>1739616101355231</id>
    <utente>USER2</utente>
    <esercizio>BENCH PRESS</esercizio>
    <massimale>95</massimale>
    <data>2022-07-30</data>
  </atleta>
</massimali>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're dealing with two xml files, you should be using an xml parser with xpath, like this:

```
#load the files
$ese = simplexml_load_file("esercizi.xml");
$mas = simplexml_load_file("massimali.xml");

#load each file into xml
$masdoc = new SimpleXMLElement($mas);
$esedoc = new SimpleXMLElement($ese);

#get the athletes in the first file
$masatletas = $masdoc->xpath('//atleta');    

#now loop through them:
foreach($masatletas as $masatleta) {
 $masute =  $masatleta->xpath('.//utente')[0];
 $masese = $masatleta->xpath('.//esercizio')[0];
 $masmas = $masatleta->xpath('.//massimale')[0];

 #this is the critical directive: look for the each artist in the other file
 #and check to see if the credentials are the same:     
 $target = $esedoc->xpath("//sessione[.//utente= '{$masute}'][.//esercizio= '{$masese}']");

 if (count($target) == 1) {
           #if so, change the value to fit that of its equivalent in the first:
           $newmas = $target[0]->xpath('.//massimale/text()')[0];
           $newmas[0] = $masmas;
           }
}
echo $esedoc->asXml();
```

EDIT:

For your modified files, change the for loop as follows:

```
foreach($masatletas as $masatleta) {
        $masute =  $masatleta->xpath('.//utente/.')[0];
        $masese = $masatleta->xpath('.//esercizio/.')[0];
        $masmas = $masatleta->xpath('.//massimale/.')[0];
        $targets= $esedoc->xpath("//sessione[.//utente = '{$masute}'][.//esercizio = '{$masese}']");
        foreach ($targets as $target){
                    $newmas = $target->xpath('.//massimale')[0];
                    $newmas[0] = $masmas;
                    };
    };
```

and it should work.

Comment: Thank you for help me. With your code i have error like :Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 6: parser error : Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found in C:\wamp64\www\xm\ord.php on line 16  so i have change something

Comment: the problem is that I have many ESERCIZI but a MASSIMALE only for exercise.
that single MASSIMALE must be inserted in the ESERCIZ Iwhere the utente and the esercizio correspond.... i'm trying

Comment: @ste I can't help you with the issue in the first comment, since that involves your actual xml; I can only work with the sample xml in the question. As to the 2nd comment, I don't really understand it and, in any case, you have already posted your own answer.

Comment: I only have a maximum value that must be entered in many exercises when the exercise and user values coincide.
I'm new I was wrong to post my answer.
Thanks anyway for helping me

Comment: @ste It's ok, everyone was new once... But I still don't understand the problem: does the answer (yours or mine) not work? Is the problem that you have a different `massimali.xml` for each exercise but only one `esercizi.xml` and you have to load the `massimali.xml`s one after the other to fill in the blanks in the exercise file?

Comment: I have a file called MASSIMALI.XML with the MASSIMALI value of each exercise.
I have a file called ESERCIZI.XML where the exercises  are inserted.
in the ESERCIZI.XML file the same exercise is written several times with repetition and % of MASSIMALE different.
I have to load the MASSIMALE value of that exercise in each exercise written in the exercise.xml file where "utente" and "esercizio" match.
in your example you use a loop on the values of the MASSIMALI.XML file which are less than the values contained in the exercise file so the maximal is added only in the first exercises

Comment: @ste "which are less than the values contained in the exercise file" - I don't really understand that. Can you edit your question and change the sample xmls such that the answer fails?

Comment: I have modified I hope it is clearer thanks

Comment: @ste I think we're getting closer! But not yet: in the `esercizi` file `USER1` appears 4 times in 4 sessions, each time doing `BENCH PRESS`s. In the `massimali` file `USER1` and `BENCH PRESS` appear together only once, with a `<massimale>` score of `100`. So the `<massimale>` value in the `esercizi`  file should be the same  `100` 4 times?

Comment: yes i can add 10 or more BENCH PRESS of the USER1 and the value of MASSIMALE it must be the same .

Comment: @ste - See edit.

Answer (score 0):

This work fine

```
$xmlFile = file_get_contents('files/esercizi_in_sessione.xml');
$xml_ese= str_replace(['&lt;','&gt;'],['<','>'], $xmlFile);

$xmlFile1 = file_get_contents('files/massimali.xml');
$xml_mas= str_replace(['&lt;','&gt;'],['<','>'], $xmlFile1);




#load the files
#$ese = simplexml_load_file("files/esercizi_in_sessione.xml");
#$mas = simplexml_load_file("massimali.xml");

#load each file into xml
$masdoc = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_mas);
$esedoc = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_ese);

#get the athletes in the first file
$masatletas = $masdoc->xpath('//atleta');    

#now loop through them:

foreach($masatletas as $masatleta) {
  
 $masute =  $masatleta->xpath('.//utente')[0];
 $masese = $masatleta->xpath('.//esercizio')[0];
 $masmas = $masatleta->xpath('.//massimale')[0];

 #this is the critical directive: look for the each artist in the other file
 #and check to see if the credentials are the same:     
 $target = $esedoc->xpath("//sessione[.//utente= '{$masute}'][.//esercizio= '{$masese}']");

 if (count($target) == 1) {
           #if so, change the value to fit that of its equivalent in the first:
           $newmas = $target[0]->xpath('.//massimale')[0];
           $newmas[0] = $masmas;
           }
}




echo $esedoc->asXml('files/prova.xml');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).